# How do i set java maximum heap space in google colab notebook?

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory

I understand that you have to use xmx to set maximum heap size. But how do you do this in colab notebook.

I am trying !java -Xmx8g. Is this right?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using *python-weak-wrapper*, use this:

```
jvm.start(max_heap_size="512m")
```

Source: https://fracpete.github.io/python-weka-wrapper3/api.html